# Loop through folder and all its subfolders to print out filenames

Tags: javascript, html, file, subdirectory, filesystemobject

Right now my code prints out all the files in a certain directory, but I am trying to get it so that my code loops through all the folders and subfolders in a certain directory and print out every file within it.

```
function ShowFiles() {
    var dir = "C:\\Users\\example...";
    fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    fsofolder = fso.GetFolder(dir);
    colFolders = fsofolder.SubFolders;
    colFiles = fsofolder.Files;
    fc = new Enumerator(colFiles);

    var counter = 0;
    var txtOutput = "";

    for(; !fc.atEnd(); fc.moveNext()) {
         txtOutput += fc.item(); 
         counter++;     
    //}

       document.getElementById("divFiles").innerHTML = txtOutput;        
}
```

Comment: You want to use a recursive function, so `ShowFiles` should test each item and if it is a directory call it self. It then should return a list of files to append to the final result.